# Return NULL or nothing from function

Tags: c

I have some functions where I would like to return NULL on failure, and on success they do not need to return anything. I have been using `void * function_name(...)`, but it still requires me to return something.

The reason I am doing this is to detect failure as part of a python C extension and they recommend that the innermost function set any exception, return NULL and then do that up through the stack.

What is the best practice in this situation? Return 0, -1 or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many functions in C return 0 for success and !0 for failure; that's a good starting convention but at first can appear a little odd.

!0 can be enhanced to error codes at a later date (or some useful data like the return of strcmp yielding the position of the first difference); retaining 0 for OK.

Answer (score 5):

In pure C terms, the easiest is to return a Boolean flag indicating success/failure.

As far as integration with Python is concerned, another approach is:

```
PyObject* func() {
    ...
    if (error) {
        /* set the exception */
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_..., ...); /* TODO: fill in as appropriate */
        return NULL;
    }
    /* return None */
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Comment: Or, if there is the slimmest chance you'd want to report more precise error conditions in the future. Return some enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to return `int`, return `0` for success, return a negative value like `-1` for failure, this follows many of the library functions.

The advantage is, there are usually multiple kinds of failure, you can return different `int` to represent them.

On the other hand, using the function in an `if` statement would seem a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

As you are in C you can't use BOOLEAN true or false. But return 1 or 0 is fine.

But you can do this in that way :

```
int yourFunction( ... )
{
   ...
   if ( success )
      return 1;
   return 0;
}
```

or even :

```
typedef int BOOL;
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

BOOL yourFunction()
{
    if ( success )
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

or return -1 and 0 as it is suggested in another response.